# Getting a error 500 in my code but not in my browser

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to use theDuckDuck go api with this code

```
val mainVal = searchQuery.replace(" ", "+")
    val url = URL("https://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=$mainVal&format=json")
    println(url.host)
    url.openConnection()
    val json = url.readText()
```

I am getting this error as a result

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=duck+duck+go&format=json
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1919)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1515)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
at java.base/java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1139)
at kotlin.io.TextStreamsKt.readBytes(ReadWrite.kt:150)
at com.andromeda.araserver.skills.GetInfo.getFast(GetInfo.kt:82)
at com.andromeda.araserver.skills.GetInfo.searchBing(GetInfo.kt:43)
at com.andromeda.araserver.skills.GetInfo.main(GetInfo.kt:28)
at com.andromeda.araserver.Run.serve(Run.java:98)
at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$HTTPSession.execute(NanoHTTPD.java:945)
at fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD$ClientHandler.run(NanoHTTPD.java:192)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

When I run the given link in my browser it returns the expected result. I tried using the HttpSConnection method, it did not work.

note I have used this methood literly hundreds of times on https, thats not the issue.

Comment: What does 500 mean?

Comment: it is an HTTP 500 error, an unspecified internal server error

Comment: And you have one Answer. Did it help? Why dont you tell? WHy dont you react?

Comment: I am away from my laptop at this time, I can test it 5 minutes or so.

Comment: this document is useful  : https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request#request-json

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added **INTERNET** permission in Manifest

&

Instead adding "+" use **Uri.encode** method for encoding URLs :

```
//        val mainVal = searchQuery.replace(" ", "+")

            val mainVal = Uri.encode(searchQuery)

            val url = URL("https://api.duckduckgo.com/?q=$mainVal&format=json")
            println(url.host)
            url.openConnection()
            val json = url.readText()
            println("Result = " + json)
```